# convert double to int

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

What is the best way to convert a `double` to an `int`? Should a cast be used?

Comment: define "best". depends if you want up/down rounding, etc.

Comment: @RPM1984: Define `etc.` :)

Comment: @Armen - touche` :) Doesn't really matter anyway - Skeet is here, nothing else matters.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

You can use a cast if you want the default truncate-towards-zero behaviour. Alternatively, you might want to use `Math.Ceiling`, `Math.Round`, `Math.Floor` etc - although you'll still need a cast afterwards.

Don't forget that the range of `int` is much smaller than the range of `double`. A cast from `double` to `int` won't throw an exception if the value is outside the range of `int` in an unchecked context, whereas a call to `Convert.ToInt32(double)` will. The result of the cast (in an unchecked context) is explicitly undefined if the value is outside the range.

Comment: I am wondering if in 64 bits machine, Convert.ToInt32 is not OK any more?

Comment: @user: The size of an `int` is always 32 bits, regardless of whether you're using a 32 or 64 bit machine.

Comment: And doubles can be much huger than even a 64 bit int.

Comment: For C# noobs like me: both Math and Convert are part of System.  
So the complete answer looks like this : `intVal = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(dblVal));`

Comment: @user1290746: That would work, but you'd usually just have `using System;` at the top of the file, at which point it could just be `intVal = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(dblVal));`

Comment: Obviously that is obvious to anyone familiar with C#.  And someone searching for an answer about type conversion is possibly/likely completely unfamiliar with the language -  that was the case for me anyway - so thanks for your extra info.

Comment: @user1290746: But in that case, I don't think the right solution is to advise people to use the fully-qualified names - the better solution is to learn about `using` directives.

Comment: Interesting that in VB.Net Double to Integer cast like `CInt(Double)` compiles to the default `Math.Round(Double)` call and `conv.ovf.i4`, but in C# `(int)double` compiles to `conv.i4`. In VB.Net `CInt(1.5)` is 2, but in C# `(int)1.5` is 1.

Answer (score 51):

Yeah, why not?

```
double someDouble = 12323.2;
int someInt = (int)someDouble;
```

Using the `Convert` class works well too.

```
int someOtherInt = Convert.ToInt32(someDouble);
```

Comment: Important to note: If someDouble was 12323.5, the (int) and Convert.ToInt32 conversions would give different results.

Comment: Good point. It appears to do banker's rounding (rounding to even), implementation appears to do so. [Convert.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.1/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Convert.cs#L1054) Whereas casting simply truncates the decimal part out.

Answer (score 44):

if you use cast, that is, `(int)SomeDouble` you will truncate the fractional part. That is, if `SomeDouble` were 4.9999 the result would be 4, not 5. Converting to int doesn't round the number. If you want rounding use `Math.Round`

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to simply use `Convert.ToInt32`. It is fast and also rounds correctly.

Why make it more complicated?

Comment: You are right. The only important point to pay additional attention is what Jon Skeet has written: "Don't forget that the range of int is much smaller than the range of double"

Answer (score 6):

`Convert.ToInt32` is the best way to convert

Comment: This a typically unsafe function because it accepts just anything.

Answer (score 3):

My ways are :

```
 - Convert.ToInt32(double_value)
 - (int)double_value
 - Int32.Parse(double_value.ToString());
```

Comment: Don't you think the third way is unnecessarily complex and slow?

Comment: The third will not work with doubles with fractional parts.  e.g., `double_value = 0.1`

Comment: I think u can use Math.Floor.

Answer (score 2):

None of the code samples exhibit the normal behaviour a school kid would expect (that halves are rounded up).  What most people would expect is is this:

```
double d = 1.5;
int i = (int)Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a complete example**

```
class Example 
{    
  public static void Main() 
  {    
    double x, y; 
    int i; 

    x = 10.0; 
    y = 3.0; 

    // cast double to int, fractional component lost (Line to be replaced) 
    i = (int) (x / y); 
    Console.WriteLine("Integer outcome of x / y: " + i); 
  }    
}
```

**If you want to round the number to the closer integer do the following:**

```
i = (int) Math.Round(x / y); // Line replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no better. It really depends on what you want, performance, accuracy, etc.

But see differences
https://dotnetfiddle.net/kwqF2M

```
double testeDouble_min = 12.3456;
double testeDouble_max = 12.8456;
double emptyDouble;

int i01_min = Convert.ToInt32(testeDouble_min); //12
int i01_max = Convert.ToInt32(testeDouble_max); //13
//var erro = Convert.ToInt32(emptyDouble); //error  

int i02_min = (int)testeDouble_min; //12
int i02_max = (int)testeDouble_max; //12
//var erro = (int)emptyDouble; //error  

var styles = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
var provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
bool success = int.TryParse(testeDouble_min.ToString(), styles, provider, out int i03_min); //0

_ = int.TryParse(testeDouble_max.ToString(),  out int i03_max); //0 because it has decimal place, if it didn't have ok

int i04_min = (int)Math.Round(testeDouble_min, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //12
int i04_max = (int)Math.Round(testeDouble_max, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //13
```

About IL there are no big differences between
`(int)` or `Convert.ToInt32`

```
var dd = 12.3;
int a = (int)dd;
```

[result](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgZgAIMiBhIgbzyNpONQBYiBZACgEoqa7eA3MACcicOEQC8RTOgB0BANw9edAJYA7YETASibdcA6jFuXgF88poA):

> ```
>     IL_0000: nop
>     IL_0001: ldc.r8 12.3
>     IL_000a: stloc.0
>     IL_000b: ldloc.0
>     IL_000c: conv.i4
>     IL_000d: stloc.1
>     IL_000e: ret
> ```

*(int) in theory less instructions tend to be faster, but I doubt anyone can measure that.*

And

```
var dd = 12.3;
int b = Convert.ToInt32(dd);
```

[result](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgZgAIMiBhIgbzyNpONQBYiBZACgEoqa7eA3MACcicOEQC8RTOgB0BANw9etAJYA7YEQBGE8gHs1fAKaDgMgCp6AkhoLo2ojoty8AvnldA=):

> ```
>     IL_0000: nop
>     IL_0001: ldc.r8 12.3
>     IL_000a: stloc.0
>     IL_000b: ldloc.0
>     IL_000c: call int32 [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Convert::ToInt32(float64)
>     IL_0011: stloc.1
>     IL_0012: ret
> ```

Answer (score 0):

int myInt = (int)Math.Ceiling(myDouble);

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.0#methods) class.
It offers all type of conversion methods whether from int to double, double to float or byte etc.

```
int i= Convert.ToInt32(500*3.142456778)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score -1):

```
label8.Text = "" + years.ToString("00") + " years";
```

when you want to send it to a label, or something, and you don't want any fractional component, this is the best way

```
label8.Text = "" + years.ToString("00.00") + " years";
```

if you want with only 2, and it's always like that

Comment: This is most certainly **not the best way** and you should probably retract your answer. By using `ToString` you're newing up a lot of other costly resources behind the scenes, like a string formatter and parser which are meant for special purposes. Learn from the answers given here. The closest to best way is to cast to `int` and truncate the fractional part or use something like `Math.Round` to get to the closest `int` you're looking for.