# How to Convert string to byte[] without conversion in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert `string` to `byte[]` without conversion/changing value.
Example:
`string` value `"10,34,56,64,32"` after converting to `byte[]` also should be `{ 10, 34, 56, 64, 32 }`.

This one is giving me unexpected result:

```
var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("10,34,56,64,32");
```

Comment: Question is fairly straightforward. One suggestion might be to show what the "unexpected result" is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552625/difference-between-casting-parsing-and-converting

Comment: Thanks @GeoffJames!

Comment: @GeoffJames Question is absolutely straight forward. It's just not researched *nearly* enough. The output wouldn't be unexpected if OP had read the documentation for the method. But anyway. An answer has been provided.

Comment: @J.Steen absolutely agree. lol'ing all the way at your comment...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
byte[] result = "10,34,56,64,32".Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: If needed also .Trim(new char[]{'{','}'})

Comment: @DanielFrühauf God no. `Split` doesn't include the character it splits on, and even if it did you could just `Trim(',')`

Comment: He had "{" and "}" in his string before in the question.

Comment: @DanielFrühauf Likely an artefact from OP reading the debugger visualiser output, rather than what's actually in the variable.

Comment: @DanielFrühauf Ah, sorry, I see what you mean. I think that was just debugger output, as J. Steen said.

Comment: @TamásSzabó Yeah. In the code example there are no brackets.