# How do you convert a double to an int?

Tags: c#

```
double one = tips[0];

double two = tips[1];
double three = tips[2];
double four = tips[3];
double five = tips[4];
double six = tips[5];
double seven = tips[6];

int average = one, two, three, four, five, six, seven;
```

The compiler is saying I need to convert a double to int but I don't know how.
This is all I find on the internet.

```
public static double ToDouble(
    int value
)
```

But I don't understand it and don't know how to put it in my code to make it work.

Comment: easiest way -> `int a = (int)yourDoubleVariable`

Comment: `int average = one, two, three, four, five, six, seven;` You know this is completely invalid, right?

Comment: Please use the search more

Comment: I need to put one, two .... together to compute average could I do  "double average = (one + two + three + four + five + six + seven) / 7;"

Answer (score 1):

You may cast it:

```
double d = 0;
int i = (int)d;
```

or convert it:

```
double d = 0;
int i = Convert.ToInt32(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(int)` to cast a `double` to an `int`, however the `average` should be `double`. For calculating the `average`, you should use `LINQ`:

```
double average = tips.Average();
//or
int average = (int) tips.Average();
```

Comment: I cant figure out how to get it to a int but it just looks easier to keep it a double

Comment: @user2676862 that's the job of the `compiler`, we just provide the correct `syntax`.

Answer (score 1):

To actually compute your average, use LINQ! Namely [`Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable<double>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946.aspx)

```
double[] tips = new[] { 1.4, 2.6, 3.2 };

double average = tips.Average();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToInt32();
```

or

```
Int.parse();
```

Comment: Convert yes, parse no, parse accepts string not double, so you need convert double to string, then string to int, not good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the static [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class.

The result would be:

```
var myInt = Convert.ToInt32(myDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
int varInt = Convert.ToInt32(varDouble);
```

and also check this other answer: [convert double to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181942/convert-double-to-int)