# How would a double NOT be rounded when converted to an int?

Tags: c#, int, switch-statement, double

When trying to run this my const are getting rounded when they are
 being converted into int from double. Is there a way to avoid the
 rounding from happening?

```
    const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL1 = 1.2;
    const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL2 = 1.375;
    const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL3 = 1.55;
    const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL4 = 1.725;
    const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL5 = 1.9;           

    int activityLevel = lstActivityLevel.SelectedIndex;
        switch (activityLevel)
        {
            case 0:
                activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL1);
                break;

            case 1:
                activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL2);
                break;

            case 2:
                activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL3);
                break;

            case 3:
                activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL4);
                break;

            case 4:
                activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL5);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: How would a double NOT be rounded when converted to an int?

Comment: Obvously you cant have a floating point number in an integer variable. If you want to keep the floating part, why do you convert it to int?!

Comment: What did you even expect to happen here? It's an _integer_. Surprisingly enough it doesn't have a fractional part o.0

Comment: Surprised..!, it is an `integer`, It's a part of behavior, Why you convert so?

Comment: look at this one [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181942/convert-double-to-int)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're re-using the `activityLevel` variable when you shouldn't be. I suspect that you really what `activityLevel` to be a `double`.

Here's how you should code this:

```
double[] activityLevels = new [] { 1.2, 1.375, 1.55, 1.725, 1.9 };
double activityLevel = activityLevels[lstActivityLevel.SelectedIndex - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Integers cannot have decimal places, so everything after your decimal place is being dropped when converted from `double` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem want set `activityLevel` to one of `const` varialbe. Here is the way to do:

```
const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL1 = 1.2;
const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL2 = 1.375;
const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL3 = 1.55;
const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL4 = 1.725;
const double ACTIVTY_LEVEL5 = 1.9;

double activityLevel = 0;
switch (lstActivityLevel.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL1;
        break;

    case 1:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL2;
        break;

    case 2:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL3;
        break;

    case 3:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL4;
        break;

    case 4:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL5;
        break;
}
lblBMRResult.Text = (BMR * activityLevel).ToString();
```