# Can't find location of implicit cast

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the total of two given number arrays for my assignment, but I keep receiving the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
int[] firstarray= new int[4] { 4, 20, 60, 150 };
double[] secondarray= new double[4] { 5, 40.5, 65.4, 145.98 };

firstarray[0] = 20;
secondarray[1] = 5;

int totalarrays = firstarray[0] + secondarray[1];
Console.WriteLine("Total of the two arrays " + totalarrays);
```

Comment: `int totalarays = firstarray[0] + secondarray[1];` You're doing math with a double and trying to contain it in integer `totalarays`.

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: `var totalarrays = firstarray[0] + secondarray[1];` (please, notice, `var`) and let compiler find out the type for you.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says - you're trying to put a double in an int but there's no implicit conversion from double to int (nor should there be as it would entail a potential loss of information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int totalarays = firstarray[0] + secondarray[1];
```

should be

```
double totalarays = firstarray[0] + secondarray[1];
```

An `int` + a `double` ends up in a `double`. If it didn't you would lose the precision of the `double` in the result - there is no implicit way to do that.

If you need to convert the `double` to an `int` there are [many different techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181942/convert-double-to-int) depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
int totalarays = firstarray[0] + secondarray[1];
```

You are trying to add a double (secondarray[1]) and an int (firstarray[0]), and convert the result to an int. This could lose precision, because the decimal part of the double value will be removed by rounding down. This is what the compiler is warning you about.

To indicate that you're happy with it, you can write:

```
int totalarays = firstarray[0] + (int)secondarray[1];
```

This is *explicitly converting* the double value to an int, by means of a cast.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
int totalarrays = firstarray[0] + Int32.Parse(secondarray[1].ToString());
```