# What is the best way to convert a Double to an Integer

Tags: vb.net

**Option Strict** was *off* in my VB app so I have now turned it on. I now have some errors that I am unsure on how to fix:

```
pnlWait.Top = (Height - pnlWait.Height) / 2
```

In C# I would just do:

```
pnlWait.Top = (int)(Height - pnlWait.Height) / 2;
```

But this doesn't work in VB.  I tried `Decimal.ToInt32` but then it complains because it is creating a `Double` with the division and there is no `Double.ToInt32`.  `Interger.Parse` requires a `String`, so this can't be any good.

```
pnlWait.Top = Integer.Parse(((Height - pnlWait.Height) / 2).ToString) 'Yeah, right!
```

That makes me think `CType` or `DirectCast` may be good, but these methods work on many objects so I don't think they could be efficient.

Comment: I always use Convert.ToInt32([double])

Comment: for that *particular* code you can use integer division: `pnlWait.Top = (Height - pnlWait.Height) \ 2`

Comment: The reference material [Type Conversion Functions (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) recommends using the language implemented conversion operators and leaving it to the compiler to select a conversion method. I am somewhat ambivalent about what constitutes the best conversion method.  Some methods involve rounding that you should be aware of and others may follow a call chain that affects performance,  My advise is to know the tools you use; i.e. RTFM. :)

Comment: or bit shift `pnlWait.Top = (Height - pnlWait.Height) >> 1` for micro optimization and to confuse anyone looking at the code :]

Answer (score 1):

```
pnlWait.Top = Convert.ToInt32((Me.Height - pnlWait.Height) / 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

After going over the link tinman posted I believe the best choice is to use the VB.Net specific conversion functions.  I initially avoided them thinking they were hold overs from VB but it seems they are not.  I was sold when it mentioned that they are compiled inline, so I will use CInt and the others.

Except in my example, I will use the suggestion offered by Plutonix.  I completely forgot about that one.

So generally I will use

```
pnlWait.Top = CInt((Height - pnlWait.Height) / 2)
```

And

```
If DR.Item(Mailings.WelcomePacket.SelectToMail) Then
```

Becomes

```
If CBool(DR.Item(Mailings.WelcomePacket.SelectToMail)) Then
```

Except

```
pnlWait.Top = (Height - pnlWait.Height) \ 2
```

is much cleaner.

Comment: I would use the last version with the integer division. `(int)` rounds towards 0, but `CInt` rounds towards even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181942/convert-double-to-int/4181954#comment68670590_4181954 so `3 \ 2` is 1, but `CInt(1.5)` is 2. Also, `CBool(object)` trows Exception if conversion to Boolean fails (for example `DBNull.Value`), so I would recommend `object.Equals(True)` or `True.Equals(object)`